# Exim: Send mail to secondary address as well as retrying delivery

Tags: exim

I am trying to set Exim up so that, after a certain period of time, emails are forwarded to a secondary address as well as still sitting in the undelivered queue with delivery attempts to the original destination occurring. I'm not sure if it's possible.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: That secondary address should be always deliverable, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in exim - no, I don't think so.
But you can always write script for the cron job and check for all messages with original recipient still not delivered to it (`exiqgrep -r <regexp> -o <seconds> -i`) and then parse output of mailq to check if second one was not added before, and next you can use `exim -Mar` to add this secondary one to message.